# Testing ruby script

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, cucumber

I'm creating a Ruby (not Rails) script and I have to test using standard Rails unit tests and Cucumber. I can't use RSpec.

So how do I test a ruby script with Cucumber and Rails Test::Unit? Is it possible?

Comment: Yes it's possible, for cucumber it should suffice to create a feature file and a step definition.  Make sure the step definition requires the stuff you want to test.

Comment: Can you please show me how to do it?

Comment: Unfortunately I have no example code here. The best way to start is to make a mini project using the six steps on the http://cukes.info/ page. The feautere def must have a file ending .feature, the step definition _step.rb IIRC.

Comment: @Philip, the only difficult I would have is how to make it worked without Rails? Meaning "only with pure ruby".

Comment: Alan, you need multiple files.  I strongly recommend you to create a toy project first.  It must consist of the following files: toy.rb, features/sometest.feature, features/step_definitions/sometest_step.rb.  Copy&Paste the contents from http://cukes.info (Main page).  Then execute cucumber features/sometest.feature

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here, I created a complete example including a Rakefile for convenience.  The file structure is this:

```
./notepad.rb
./Rakefile
./test
./test/test_notepad.rb
./features
./features/add_note.feature
./features/step_definitions
./features/step_definitions/add_note_step.rb
```

In fact this example doesn't even use classes, so you can really test typical "Scripts" with it.  File contents are here: http://pastebin.com/sJUP7VSA

So in the end you can do this:

```
$ rake test
Finished tests in 0.001368s, 730.9942 tests/s, 1461.9883 assertions/s.

1 tests, 2 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips

$ rake cucumber
1 scenario (1 passed)
2 steps (2 passed)
0m0.002s
```

Cheers, Philip